# CSS media query latency in Chrome?

Tags: css, django, responsive-design, media-queries

Having a really strange experience right now trying to implement responsive CSS media queries on a web app I'm working on and just want to see if anyone has any theories on why this might be happening.

Here's some context:

- Working on a Django app, running on localserver (localhost:8000 from manage.py runserver)
- Was just modifying style.css file and everything was OK.  If I made a change in style.css, refreshed the change, my work looked fine in the browser
- I'm testing browser compatibility in Chrome & Firefox right now

So workflow was proceeding normally until I started writing some media queries at the bottom of the same style.css file.  An example being:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
    #hero .user-actions {
       float: left;
       width: auto;
    }
}
```

And here's what's happening in Chrome: After I write and save that query, if I reduce my browser width from, say 1200px to 1000px to test the change (measured via multiple 3rd party apps), no change - the media queries aren't being detected at all.  I don't see the media query in elements in Chrome browser webmaster tools (but they show up fine in Firefox and other browsers).  I've tried (1) clearing my Chrome browser cache, (2) going back into terminal and running

```
manage.py collectstatic
```

I've looked at my meta viewport tags, I've checked my CSS syntax and I don't know why it's not reading it specifically in Chrome.  Now, what's bizarre is that if I reduce my Chrome browser size FURTHER down to 965px width or narrower, all of a sudden my max-width 1080px media queries show up and start working in Chrome. So it's like there's 115px of margin before chrome picks up the media query. Huh? Has anybody ever experienced anything like this before? Is there some setting in Chrome or something I'm not thinking of that might be causing this?
I looked at a few other posts and saw references to a -webkit zoom bug, but that's not the case here.

Comment: Providing a small codepen or jsfiddle sample that reproduces the problem might help people provide you with an answer.

Comment: @JamesHolderness - and the rest of us!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer ... But I have a media query loading/caching issue too.
It started out last week in my **Chrome Canary** and since this morning I feel the same pain (yes it is painful) in my **Chrome Dev (29.0.1521.3)**.

My media queries

```
<link media="screen,projection,tv" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link media="only screen and (min-width:250px) and (max-width:500px)" href="responsive-mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link media="print" href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Strange. I've implemented my responsive media queries last summer and didn't face any problem until **Canary** started caching my `responsive-mobile.css` file last week. Then I realized that Canary (and now Chrome Dev) is loading my `print.css` file ounce my `responsive-mobile.css` gets loaded after streching my browser's viewport from large to small and back.

So no, I don't have answer sorry. But a bunch of questions. ;)